# How to get studentized residuals from pgls() in Caper R package

Tags: r, regression, phylogeny

I have a dataset with 135 species, 6 life history traits (response) and 2 environmental variables(predictor). I am interested in doing a pgls regression analysis using the package Caper to look at the influence of the environmental variables on each of the life history traits. As one of the traits is female body mass, I calculated pgls regressions of each trait against female body mass and used the subsequent residuals in multivariate regressions against the environmental variables. To check that the regression diagnostics are okay in univariate trait regressions against body mass, I used plot.pgls(). The plots showed the presence of some outliers. In some papers that used pgls in Caper, data points with studentized residuals >3 have been excluded as outliers.

1. Can someone help me figure out how to calculate studentized residuals from a pgls regression in Caper?
2. The pgls regression gives phylogenetic and non-phylogenetic residuals. Which one of these are studentized residuals calculated on?

Thank you for your time and help, 
pb

Comment: Can you put together a small, reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this website where there is a detailed worked-out example of how to calculate standardized residuals from pgls() in Caper and diagnose outliers. 
http://www.anthrotree.info/wiki/pages/w5j9m8/7.5.html

PBA